# Are discretionary bonuses in finance roles essentially scams?

Tags: motivation, compensation, bonus

I started working for a hedge fund in a backoffice/midoffice kind of spot and I'm trying to see how the discretionary bonuses aren't just a scam to trick people into working long hours.

I understand bonuses are supposed to encourage 'top performance'. However, the actual bonus seems to be determined by some biannual peer review political game/popularity contest. I see coworkers working long hours, being super deferent to more 'important' people in other teams (often doing their work for them), and trying very hard to be highly available. It all seems like a lot of extra hours over a full year for an unknown with no guarantee that is actually likely to lower one's effective hourly pay rate not raise it.

I thought a better way to bonus hunt would be find some big inefficiency, do a quick analysis to demonstrate the PnL hit, and then make a recommendation/implementation to improve. I found one. However, I feel like my boss would just poach this idea since it takes time and he'd find out a little after the analysis step what I'm doing (knowing what I'm doing IS his job). Then, he brings it up with his superiors and allocates resources or whatever in meetings I don't get invited to and quite simply I don't see how many name as the source of the idea ever gets out beyond my boss.

I do see how he links his name to it and gets a nice bonus if it works and if the higher ups remember and override the whole peer review nonsense.

So, it feels like bonuses are a scam to me and one should just work slightly above the minimum.

What am I missing? How should I go about bonus hunting and improve the odds of actually getting a good bonus without just being a dupe that works absurd hours and answers emails at 11pm and on weekends on a regular basis?

Comment: If you "do see how he links his name to it and gets a nice bonus if it works", that implies that the bonus is _not_ a scam.  A scam would mean that _no attainable bonus exists_.  It sounds more like what is happening is that your boss is poaching other people's bonuses by taking credit for their ideas.  So instead of taking your idea to your boss directly, take it to him and any relevant supervisors simultaneously by including them in the discussion from day one.

Comment: You might consider reading Michael Lewis' book _Liar's Poker_ to get some idea of the prevailing mindset in your chosen field.

Comment: This question is totally deserving of my upvote.

Answer (score 6):

Isn't that the whole point of working for a hedge fund?

That everybody on the bottom does all the work, at the expense of their health and sanity, knowing full well they are being taken advantage of, for the glimmer of hope that they will get the chance to be the guy who gets million dollar bonuses, takes 3 hour lunches with clients and gets to take advantage of people below him/her?  They aren't working for the bonus at the end of the year despite what it seems.  They are working to be the guy who is politically connected and takes advantage of others because that is the guy that gets the amazing bonus.

In many ways it operates more like a fraternity than a typical business.  You accept hazing because you believe you will have a shot at being the guy on top some day.

Answer (score 1):

*If* your boss is the kind that just steals good ideas and will not pay a bonus for this, what's to keep him from not paying a bonus for overtime?

Put differently: bonuses should reward good performance and keep good performers from leaving. Do you have grounds for believing your boss will tick off someone who made a major contribution and possibly cause you to leave? Most bosses I know would be happy to show off their star underling, bask in his reflected glory and hope you come up with more good ideas, year after year - and pay you a bonus to make sure you stay.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I go about bonus hunting and improve the odds of actually
>   getting a good bonus without just being a dupe that works absurd hours
>   and answers emails at 11pm and on weekends on a regular basis?

Talk to your boss. Ask how bonuses work at your company. And ask "What should I do to put myself into position to get a good bonus?" In your conversation try to get past the "what HR says about bonuses" and into the "what actually happens at your company".

In some companies, bonuses are earned due to single important events ("land a key account", "complete an important research project on time", "deliver a software release in time for an annual user meeting").

In other companies, bonuses are earned by some sort of metric ("score at least 90 on the '360 degrees feedback questionnaire' ").

In many companies it's a mix of imposed goals, agreed-upon goals, company performance, and subjective factors.

Nobody here can tell you whether that will mean you must work "absurd hours" or not. Only your boss can tell you that.

From your words ("scam", "dupe" "absurd"), it seems as if you have already drawn your own conclusion. Try to confirm that with your boss rather than just assuming. Then decide what you want to do about it (if anything), other than just be unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

Change your thinking for your own sanity. Everybody works for someone else and delivers more than they get paid. Your job is to help your boss get his/her bonus. Otherwise, why do they need you? If you make a million dollars for your company, don't expect them to give you a million dollars.

I think it is counter-productive for a boss to do this without you getting any bonus because there is the risk you leaving or worse not performing in the future and being a waste of a salary.

Everyone wants to get credit and be recognized and appreciated, but it won't happen with every single thing you do. If you want to sign your name to all of your work, become an artist or work on a movie. The key is for your boss to do what is necessary to keep you productive. The company isn't going to compensate you if you don't have anything to offer.

The boss who is doing well and recognized in the company (and gets a big bonus) is in a much better position to help her team. Bad bosses aren't able to get you a raise because no one values their opinion.

If you don't get what you think you deserve, let them know. Unfortunately, you may have to start looking for another job.

Answer (score 0):

The "Bonus" is exactly that - an extra amount of money for extra work.

If you don't believe they're being handed out based on merit, but rather on politics, then simply DON'T PURSUE THEM.  You agreed to be happy with your base pay, so be happy with it.  Chasing that bonus is obviously asking more than you're comfortable doing, so let it go.  If you aren't happy with your base pay, then take steps to correct that situation.

As for "poaching" your ideas:  Get used to it.  That's the way the world works, sometimes.  Frauds are (usually) found out, eventually.

This is a game you can't win by playing halfheartedly.  You either embrace the "kill yourself for a bonus" zeitgeist, or resolve yourself to not being in the "bonus race" and focus on doing your job well regardless of acknowledgment or bonuses.

However, in my opinion, you are in the wrong place (hedge fund) to expect equitable treatment (no pun intended).  Either make peace with your situation, or change it.